# SSH error 114 when connect with FinalBuilder 7

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ssh, authentication

I'm testing FB 7 and try to connect to my Mac OS X Snow Leopard machine.

I can connect with paramiko (python SSH library) but not FB7.

The only thing I get is:

```
SSH error encoutered: 114
```

I try stopping & restarting the share session on Mac OS X.

update: I enable server debug and get this log:

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.2p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Dd'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 10.3.7.135 port 49457
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version SecureBlackbox.8
debug1: no match: SecureBlackbox.8
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: privsep_preauth: successfully loaded Seatbelt profile for unprivileged child
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 75/75
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user mamcx service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "mamcx"
Connection closed by 10.3.7.135
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.3.7.135"
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

Answer (score 1):

FinalBulder uses the SecureBlackBox library for SSH. SBB's Error 114 is:

```
ERROR_SSH_NO_MORE_AUTH_METHODS_AVAILABLE    
114 (0x0072)    
There are no more methods for user authentication
```

If your authentication details are incorrect, you should receive an "authentication failed" error: but just to be sure can you please double-check the auth details in the action?

If the Private Key File field in the SSH Open Connection action is null, then the action uses username/password authentication. If it's not null, it uses public key authentication, and the password specified is the password *for the key file*. Have you done any custom configuration of the SSH server to restrict the authentication methods available?

We haven't tested against OSX, but we did test against OpenSSH on Linux (and, for fun, against OpenSSH on my iPhone). I think we can round up an OSX box to test on if for some reason your error's OS-specific.

Disclosure: I work for VSoft Technologies. If you want to take this offline, please send us an email at support@finalbuilder.com

Comment: I use the correct auth credentials. Also, this action work fine against my hosting server (joyent/open solaris). I don't made anything to the server... I don't know what to do anyway!.

Comment: OK, I'll get the boss to bring in his macbook and I'll see if we can replicate the problem

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: We were able to fix the issue by generating a SSH key and using that private key in FinalBuilder. We never had to do this before, but I think it may be necessary because we are using an old version of FinalBuilder 7.